# Magento slow search on one site only

Tags: php, mysql, magento

We have two store fronts on Magento.
Both run fast and work fine.

However search on one of the two sites is very slow (6 seconds compared to .5 on the other store).

Nothing shows in the error logs. When I look at the varien log even mage takes more than 5 seconds on the store with the slow search.

This one is driving me nuts. Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Joris

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

You can try merging the javascript & css files by visiting magento admin. Its located under sytem >> configuration >> Advanced >> Developer >> Javascript settings and then merge javascript files to yes. Do the same for css files.

Hope this helps...

Comment: try the above answer in demo / staging site . dont try in live site directly. because i saw examples we face problems after JS or css merging.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Our css/javascript files are already combined.

The strange thing is that we run two almost identical stores, on the same server, same Magento installation. They both are super fast, except that showing search results on 1 site is a lot slower (about 5 seconds slower).